# How to interact with events from a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, tokens, events, ethereumjs, logs

can we get access to watch the event and get logged data from them and use it for processing in a smart contract?

Like matching an state variable with the data logged by an event .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, smart contracts can't read the content of the event logs. As it says in [the docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/contracts.html#events):

> The Log and its event data is not accessible from within contracts (not even from the contract that created them).